# Jquery callback function is not changing css attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I'm Trying to zoom a picture in fullscreen (later on!). Why is the container css attribute margin-left not changed within the callback function? (Scroll down please ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoom Hover</title>
        <style type="text/css">
    #container{
        margin-left:200px;
        }

    @-moz-keyframes zoom {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
                -moz-transform: translate(-200px);
            }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes 'zoom' {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
                left:0px;
                -webkit-transform: translate(-200px);
            }
    }    

.img1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

    }

.img2 {
    -moz-animation: zoom 4s;
    -webkit-animation: 'zoom' 4s;

}

</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            $("#container img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1",function(){
                        $("#container").css("margin-left","0px");});}); /*HERE WHY IS IT NOT CHANGING MARGIN-LEFT??*/
    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img class="img1" src="http://www.maplehilltree.com/CHRIST_PUNCHERS_HOOO__6_.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            $("#container img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
                $("#container").css("margin-left","0px");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**: If you want to animate the transition without jumps, try:

1.) change your javascript using JQuery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            $("#container").switchClass("test1", "", 1000).find("img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
            /*$("#container").css("margin-left","0px");*/
        });
    });
```

2.) Put a class to the container so you can use swithClass method to animate

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="test1">
        <img class="img1" src="http://www.maplehilltree.com/CHRIST_PUNCHERS_HOOO__6_.jpg"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

3.) Remove margin-left from #container and create the css class

```
.test1{
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

Hope you like it :)

Wanna check how it works? http://jsfiddle.net/dS3Jp/

Comment: hmmm like the above answer...it FIRST sets the margin to 0 and then it animates...is it also working the other way round?

Comment: hi thats looks like a goog way im getting an error $("#container").switchClass is not a function but thats my fault i guess...i think that should it be!

Comment: Check the jsfiddle as a reference. You must load JqueryUI JS file as well (with jquery.js is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put this in a callback as [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) is not asynchronous, give this a try:

```
$("#container img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
$("#container").css("margin-left", "0px");
```

Comment: @jack than he is doing it right away without doing one after the other...the whole nice zoom effect is gone then...

Answer (score 0):

removeClass doesn't take a callback function like that. It does accept a function, but it's not a callback. Read about that here: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

What you should do is change it to:

```
$("#container img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
$("#container").css("margin-left","0px");
```

To make it even shorter you could do:

```
$("#container").css("margin-left","0px").find("img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
```

Comment: that looks nice...but it totally destroys my zoom effect. the animation sets margin left to 0 and i wish it was staying like this with no jumping. i tried this...but i doesn't work : $("#container").find("img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1").css("margin-left","0px");

Comment: the problem is...it seems, that the transformation is not finished...and jquery doesn't know about it ;-) That is the problem if i mix it up ;-P Is there a qjery timeout or sth?

Comment: So when the class is removed it animates with css and you want to wait until that's finished? I'm afraid you can't do that. But if you know how long the animation is you could use jQuery delay(). http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('img').click(function() {
         $(this).addClass("img2").removeClass("img1").parent().css("margin-left","0px");
     });
});
```

Testing it out: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/nVd9N/

EDIT: Add in a delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("img2").delay(2000).removeClass("img1").delay(2000).parent().css("margin-left", "0px");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks...similar effect like the other answers...is it possible to check if the first part ist still animating?

Answer (score 0):

Your animation seems jumpy, but for setting CSS when the animation is complete, just bind the animationEnd event and use a callback, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
              $("#container img").addClass("img2").removeClass("img1");
        });
        $('#container').on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
              $("#container").css("margin-left","0px");
        });
});
```